# The content of cell does not display in iText7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

If the content of cell is bigger than height of cell in the height-fixed table, the content does not display.

This is probable a specification of iText library, but is there any way to make the content visible in iText7 in this case?

I'm migrating from iText5 to iText7.

Even though I set the same value(table and cell height, padding value, font size) as iText5, the content of cell does not display in iText7.

If I set the TopPadding and BottomPadding of Cell to 0, the content of cell does display.

I don't think that iText5 and iText have diffent coordinates and units.

How do I get the same result as iText5?

iText 5's code

```
PdfPTable ptable = new PdfPTable(1);
ptable.setTotalWidth(143f);
ptable.setWidthPercentage(100f);
PdfPCell pcell = new PdfPCell();
pcell.setPadding(2f);
pcell.setUseAscender(true);
pcell.setUseDescender(true);
pcell.setFixedHeight(16.05603f);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setLeading(4.032f, 1.0f);
p.setSpacingBefore(0f);
p.setSpacingAfter(0f);
Chunk str = new Chunk("Sample");
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("batang", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
font.setSize(12f);
str.setFont(font);
p.add(str);
pcell.addElement(p);
ptable.addCell(pcell);
ptable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 300f, 150f, contentByte);
```

iText 7's code

```
Table table = new Table(new float[] {143f});
table.setWidthPercent(100f);
table.setHeight(16.05603f);
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setPadding(2f);
cell.setHeight(16.05603f);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setFixedLeading(4.032f);
p.setMultipliedLeading(1.0f);
p.setMarginTop(0f);
p.setMarginBottom(0f);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("batang", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
Text str = new Text("Sample").setFontSize(12f).setFont(font);
p.add(str);
cell.add(p);
table.addCell(cell);
table.setFixedPosition(300f, 150f, 143f);
document.add(table);
```

Comment: *"How do I get the same result as iText5?"* - as you don't show your code, that is hard to tell. Furthermore, in the as of now short history of iText 7 the table layout code has changed the most (at least in my perception), so you should definitively also state the exact iText 7 version you use.

Comment: mkl, I added my source code, so please review it.

Comment: Please also indicate which iText 7 version exactly you use.

Comment: iText 7 version is 7.0.4.

Comment: iText5 and iText7 use same coordinates and units, but they have different layout algorithms hence different visual results. Can you describe your goal more precisely? Because if it is simply to fit the content then you managed to do so by decreasing the padding. If it was not enough, why?

Comment: My customers want to keep their PDF export informations and want to have the same results as with iText5. So it is not possible to discretionally decrease the padding of iText7.

Comment: As a result of my testing, the horizontal space is the same as iText5, but the vertical space is slightly smaller than iText5. If the problem is simply that padding or margin values ​​are different, then the horizontal space must also be different. But it is only different the vertical space, so what settings have I missed?